# C# working with fingerprint device

Tags: c#, winforms, sdk, device, fingerprint

First of all, there are 3 questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913973/zkteco-steps-to-read-thumb-impression), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921153/zkemkeeper-events-not-triggering) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144611/integrating-zkteco-tx268-with-web-app) in stack overflow, but I couldn't find any resourceful help there. I have a biometric device ZKTeco (Model tx628). Task is very simple, just to read the thumb impression from this device. I am working on visual studio 2015 windows form application. I've downloaded the sdk from the manufacturer company's website. but cannot trigger any of them. they don't even connect with the device. I could connect the device through usb connection. but this doesn't work every time (I have no idea why. though its my first time working with device and dll). I might have missing something. please enlighten me with any suggestion, link or something. *yet I didn't find my device name on their website. I have found a solution [there](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1104538/Csharp-ZKTeco-Biometric-Device-Getting-Started), but this didn't worked on mine.

Comment: At which step you are having problem?

Comment: I can't move on, because the sdk is not connecting with the device. I've tried USB, but that doesn't work everytime. I've no clue why this is happening. I've checked both 32 and 64 bit on my pc(yet mine is 64 bit) and I've integrated the dll file I got with the sdk successfully.

Comment: The SDK should include a demo app. Does that connect to the device properly?

Comment: sorry to say, I didn't find any demo app there, instead I found c# solution files under demo folder. the sdk file name was "Standalone sdk". and I've tried those solution files. they connect but no event fired from the device.

Comment: hey i am also using same device did you find any solution ?

Comment: or any method of reading file of data which contain attendance time and user etc .

Comment: do you face issue while creating the CZKEM class or while connecting? if while connecting, share the what is the getlasterror you are getting